# Replacement for <font> in html 5

Tags: html

Just for a note. I have looked at the other posts to replace font tag. I do not understand them at all. And the answers that were given are confusing. So I am asking right now.

I am making a website and I want to incorporate a specific font called "Behind Green Eyes"

Since html 5 does not support the font tag anymore. Is there a replacement I can use? And how would I use it?

Thanks to whomever helps me!

Comment: Presentational changes are handled with CSS. Use the `font` CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

Add font in css using

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Harabara Bold";
src: url("css/fonts/Harabara.eot");
src: 
url("css/fonts/Harabara.woff") format("woff"),
url("css/fonts/Harabara.otf") format("opentype"),
url("css/fonts/Harabara.svg#filename") format("svg");
}
```

Then call it like below

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Harabara Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```